# Build time error swift 4 xCode 9 with Alamofire added in pod

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4, xcode9

I was working on a project which I required to updated to support Swift 4. After making related changes, When I have run the application I got the similar error mentioned below. After which I have created a new and empty project to check which also encountered the same error.

#### What did I do?

Initially, I have created a project in xCode 9 with Swift 4 and add Alamofire in pod file and run the code without making any change in code.

#### What happened instead?

Instead of building successful, It shows an error:

```
PhaseScriptExecution \[CP\]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/rigel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xCode9Demo-fhmuhhcblhavqddwdzduqcfflaqu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xCode9Demo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xCode9Demo.build/Script-2DACA56F3034C685ED1342BD.sh
    cd /Users/rigel/Vihar/Development/Demo/Created/xCode9Demo
    /bin/sh -c /Users/rigel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xCode9Demo-fhmuhhcblhavqddwdzduqcfflaqu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xCode9Demo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xCode9Demo.build/Script-2DACA56F3034C685ED1342BD.sh

mkdir -p /Users/rigel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xCode9Demo-fhmuhhcblhavqddwdzduqcfflaqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xCode9Demo.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/rigel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xCode9Demo-fhmuhhcblhavqddwdzduqcfflaqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/rigel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xCode9Demo-fhmuhhcblhavqddwdzduqcfflaqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xCode9Demo.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Alamofire.framework/
Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Alamofire.framework/Info.plist
Alamofire.framework/_CodeSignature/
Alamofire.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources

sent 1730891 bytes  received 98 bytes  3461978.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1730337  speedup is 1.00
basename: invalid option -- 's'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

#### Alamofire Environment

**Alamofire version: 4.5.0**
**Xcode version: 9_GM(Beta)**
**Swift version: 4.0**
**Platform(s) running Alamofire: iOS 10.3.3**
**macOS version running Xcode: 10.12.6**

Anyone can please help me?

Comment: Works for me in new project using `pod 'Alamofire', '4.5.0'` with xcode 9 GM seed

Comment: Also work for me Please test it yourself creating new project. I think there is another issue in pod not installation issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending good amount of time on the surfing, I come to know that the **issue is related to the configurations, mostly hardware configurations** of a MAC I was using.
Once I have tried running the same code on another mac it works perfectly.
**This could not be the solution for all which I know** but I have shared my scenario because if someone stuck in such an issue and even after spending a good amount of time like me, don't get any solution I suggest **please check running the code in another MAC**.
I have to spend a really good amount of time on the issue, which I wish other must not.

I hope you don't have the issue but might got help from this So please don't lead the answer in any negative direction if this will not be your answer.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, I just have changed my MAC and try running the same code on that and it works for me. I am not confident its MAC issue or what but this way my issue solved.

Comment: experience same issues.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Alamofire 4.5.1

Add the following line to have Alamofire in pod file, which was built on Swift 4 and then perform pod install.

pod 'Alamofire', '4.5.1'

I tried it on Mac OS 10.12.6, Xcode 9 & Swift 4.

I hope it would be work around until the version 4.5.1 officially available. So, we can stop mentioning version in the pod file.

Comment: I have tried this also but I am unable to solve the issue. The issue is still unsolved.

Comment: have you tried on Xcode 9 stable release (not beta)? Please try if not already.

Comment: I have even gone through the stable release of xCode 9. In that also I am getting the same issue.